# Cannot open a message on the Careers 2.0 site

Tags: bug, jobs

I have received a message from a potential job on the Careers 2.0 web site and when I try to click on it all I get is the little exclamation mark popping up at the end of the message line.

Any assistance on this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

OK this seems to be working now for me at least.